# Transfer Learning model gives 0 accuracy regardless of architecture

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, transfer-learning

I am trying to develop a model using Keras and transfer learning. The dataset I am using can be found here: https://github.com/faezetta/VMMRdb.

I have taken the 10 classes of car brands with the most samples and trained two models built upon the VGG16 architecture using transfer learning, as it can be seen in the code below.

```
samples_counts = utils.read_dictionary(utils.TOP10_BRANDS_COUNTS_NAME)

train_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory=utils.TRAIN_SET_LOCATION,
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='categorical',
    class_names=list(samples_counts.keys()),
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(56, 56),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=utils.RANDOM_STATE,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset='training',
    interpolation='bilinear'
)

validation_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory=utils.TRAIN_SET_LOCATION,
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='categorical',
    class_names=list(samples_counts.keys()),
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(56, 56),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=utils.RANDOM_STATE,
    validation_split=0.2,
    subset='validation',
    interpolation='bilinear'
)

test_dataset = image_dataset_from_directory(
    directory=utils.TEST_SET_LOCATION,
    labels='inferred',
    label_mode='categorical',
    class_names=list(samples_counts.keys()),
    color_mode='rgb',
    batch_size=32,
    image_size=(56, 56),
    shuffle=True,
    seed=utils.RANDOM_STATE,
    interpolation='bilinear'
)

image_shape = (utils.RESIZE_HEIGHT, utils.RESIZE_WIDTH, 3)
base_model = apps.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet', input_shape=image_shape)
base_model.trainable = False

preprocess_input = apps.vgg16.preprocess_input
flatten_layer = layers.Flatten(name='flatten')
specialisation_layer = layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu', name='specialisation_layer')
avg_pooling_layer = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='pooling_layer')
dropout_layer = layers.Dropout(0.2, name='dropout_layer')
classification_layer = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='classification_layer')

inputs = tf.keras.Input(shape=(utils.RESIZE_HEIGHT, utils.RESIZE_WIDTH, 3))
x = preprocess_input(inputs)
x = base_model(x, training=False)

# First model
# x = flatten_layer(x)
# x = specialisation_layer(x)

# Second model
x = avg_pooling_layer(x)
x = dropout_layer(x)
outputs = classification_layer(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)

model.summary()

steps_per_epoch = len(train_dataset)
validation_steps = len(validation_dataset)
base_learning_rate = 0.0001
optimizer = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=base_learning_rate)
loss_function = losses.CategoricalCrossentropy()
train_metrics = [metrics.Accuracy(), metrics.AUC(), metrics.Precision(), metrics.Recall()]

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer,
              loss=loss_function,
              metrics=train_metrics)

initial_results = model.evaluate(validation_dataset,
                                 steps=validation_steps,
                                 return_dict=True)

training_history = model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=10, verbose=0,
                             validation_data=validation_dataset,
                             callbacks=[TqdmCallback(verbose=2)],
                             steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch,
                             validation_steps=validation_steps)

history = training_history.history
final_results = model.evaluate(test_dataset,
                              return_dict=True,
                              callbacks=[TqdmCallback(verbose=2)])
```

I keep getting 0 accuracy and bad metrics in general. I have tried the solutions mentioned in [Transfer learning bad accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994344/transfer-learning-bad-accuracy) and [MNIST and transfer learning with VGG16 in Keras- low validation accuracy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53640464/mnist-and-transfer-learning-with-vgg16-in-keras-low-validation-accuracy), without success.

The summary and the results for the first model are:

```
Model: "functional_1"
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 56, 56, 3)]       0
tf_op_layer_strided_slice (T [(None, 56, 56, 3)]       0
tf_op_layer_BiasAdd (TensorF [(None, 56, 56, 3)]       0
vgg16 (Functional)           (None, 1, 1, 512)         14714688
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 512)               0
specialisation_layer (Dense) (None, 1024)              525312
classification_layer (Dense) (None, 10)                10250

Total params: 15,250,250
Trainable params: 535,562
Non-trainable params: 14,714,688
```

```
Initial results: loss = 9.01, accuracy = 0.0, auc = 0.53, precision = 0.13, recall = 0.12
Final results: loss = 2.5, accuracy = 0.0, auc = 0.71, precision = 0.31, recall = 0.14
```

[image: Train and Test Loss and Accuracy for first model]

The summary and the results for the second model are:

```
Model: "functional_1"
input_2 (InputLayer)         [(None, 56, 56, 3)]       0
tf_op_layer_strided_slice (T [(None, 56, 56, 3)]       0
tf_op_layer_BiasAdd (TensorF [(None, 56, 56, 3)]       0
vgg16 (Functional)           (None, 1, 1, 512)         14714688
pooling_layer (GlobalAverage (None, 512)               0
dropout_layer (Dropout)      (None, 512)               0
classification_layer (Dense) (None, 10)                5130

Total params: 14,719,818
Trainable params: 5,130
Non-trainable params: 14,714,688
```

```
Initial Results: loss = 21.6, accuracy = 0, auc = 0.48, precision = 0.07, recall = 0.07
Final Results: loss = 2.02, accuracy = 0, auc = 0.72, precision = 0.44, recall = 0.009
```

[image: Train and Test Loss and Accuracy for second model]

Comment: Have you tried setting base_model.trainable=True?

Comment: No, because I don't want to retrain the VGG16 network, I only want to train the layers I've put on top (transfer learning)

Answer (score 1):

in the code below

```
# Second model
x = avg_pooling_layer(x)
x = dropout_layer(x)
outputs = classification_layer(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

you need to add a Flatten layer after the avg_pooling_layer. Or alternatively change the
ave_pooling_lay to a GlobalMaxPooling2D layer which is what I think is best. so your second model would be

```
x=tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
x = dropout_layer(x)
outputs = classification_layer(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs, outputs)
```

Also in Vgg you can set the parameter pooling='average then the output is a 1 dimensional tensor so you don't need to flatten it and you don't need to add
global average pooling. In your test_dataset and validation_dataset set shuffle=False and set seed=None.  Your values for steps_per_epoch and validation steps are incorrect. They are typically set to number of samples//batch_size. You can leave these values as None in model.fit and it will determine these values internally, also set verbose=1 so you can see the results of training for each epoch. Leave callbacks=None I don't even know what TqdmCallback(verbose=2) is. Not listed in any documentation I could find.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried your suggestions. Setting shuffle = False and seed = None and using max pooling did help, but steps_per_epoch and validation_steps ARE correct however, since the length of the dataset is computed as the number of batches available. TqdmCallback is a callback which displays progression bars, so it doesn't affect anything. I am no longer getting 0 accuracy, but the validation set results are very different from the test set results. I'll post another question for this problem.